# Вызов parent метода и модификация возвращаемого им результата

Tags: ооп, php

Привет всем! Извините за нубский вопрос, но не могу понять, почему вызов родительского метода из потомка ничего не возвращает (см. комментарии к коду).

```
<?php

// Родительский класс - машина

class Car {

        function __construct() {

                $this->brand='Daewoo';
                $this->model='Matiz';
                $this->price=250;
                $this->info='';

        }

// функция - вернуть бренд, модель и цену

        public function getInfo() {

                $this->$info=$this->brand." ".$this->model." ".$this->price;
                return $this->info;

        }
}

// Класс Старая машина (наследник)

class oldCar extends Car {

        function __construct() {

                parent::__construct();

        // Добавляем свойство "Возраст" (age)

                $this->age=3;

        }

        public function getInfo() {

        // Задумка была такой - получить результат
          //"родительской" функции getInfo() и добавить к ней возраст
          // машины (age)

        // Но при вызове ничего не выводит вообще. Где косяк?)  
          // (не тот... а который ошибка))

                $this->info=parent::getInfo()." ".$this->age;

        }

}

// собственно, вызов

$oldcar = new oldCar();
echo $oldcar->getInfo();

?>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ошибка в строчке `$this->$info=$this->brand." ".$this->model." ".$this->price;`
2. Функция  `getInfo()` у потомка ничего не возвращает
3. Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lqT3Kc)
4. Ошибки по невнимательности =)

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый и понятный ответ!) Так и знал, что у меня какая-то глупая ошибка по невнимательности. Только начинаю вникать в ООП)

Comment: Успехов в изучении)

Comment: @gregory - Если вы считаете что ответ дан полностью, его можно пометить как "Правильный" (серая галка под дизлайком) =)

Answer (score 2):

В родительском классе:

```
$this->$info
```

Заменить на:

```
$this->info
```

В классе наследнике вы забываете возвращать результат. В функции getInfo() добавьте:

```
return $this->info;
```